# Is it permissible to write blogs about cricket or football and earn money via AdSense?

Tags: halal-haram, work, internet

Is it allowed in Islam to write blogs about live cricket score and live football goals etc. and then earn via that blogs from AdSense? Actually I am a blogger and I want to start a blog about cricket where I will post daily updates about crickets. I will write about the matches and live scores.   I will be not adding any picture or videos!

Answer (score 2):

According to the a core principle of Islam,

> لا ضرر و لا ضرار - no harm for you and for others,

it is completely halal.

Comment: Can you provide some authentic source with details.